# Prove that de-bruijn graph has eulerian cycle?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, eulerian-path

**Let $G_{2,n}$ be a de-bruijn graph.**

We remove the vertex `11...11` and the vertex `00...00` and **all** edges connected to them.

**Q: For which range of values for n the new graph has Eulerian cycle?**

We know that in order for a graph to have an Eulerian cycle we must prove that $d_{in}=d_{out}$
for each vertex.

I proved that for the vertex that didn't get affected by this change $d_{in}=d_{out}=2$

But for the affected ones, that's not related to `n` and always $d_{in}$ isn't equal to $d_{out}$ 
For example: for 01...1 $d_{in}=2, d_{out}=1$

and that conradicts that there is n for which this is true.

Her's an image:
[image]

Comment: What are you asking?  There doesn't seem to be a question here.

Comment: @saulspatz For which range of values for n the new graph has Eulerian cycle? (there should be some valid values but I proved that there is no!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof can only have a flaw in it if you have overlooked an edge case for a very small value of $n$.  Your proof doesn't apply in the cases $n=1$ and $n=2$.  Write it out carefully, and note what assumptions you are making, and where you use $n>2$

When $n=1$, we delete all the vertices.  Is the graph with no vertices a graph?  Some people say yes, some say no.  If your answer is "yes", then is the path with with no vertices a cycle?  It vacuously visits all the vertices, so if it's a cycle, it's Eulerian.  I get you argue that it's a cycle, if the definition is couched in the form, "if $u$ is the initial vertex, and $v$ is the terminal vertex then $u=v$."  Anyway, this case isn't interesting.

In the $n=2$ case, there is an Eulerian cycle.  I leave this one to you.

Comment: so when n>2 there is no solution and my writing is correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: I just posted the answer and my professor said it's wrong and there is an n for which the graph has eulerian cycle

Comment: Your answer is correct for $n>2$.  As I said, there is an Eulerian cycle in the $n=1$ case.  Just draw a picture.

Comment: ok thanks, for the same conditions how may I know for which n it does have Hamiltonian  cycle?

Comment: @Daniel98 According to the site rules, you shouldn't ask new questions in comments.  If you have another question, you should post another question.  The idea is that people should be able to search for the answers to their own questions in the body of knowledge built up here, but comments won't be searched.